# Secedit does not accept updating security settings

Tags: powershell, security, scripting

I have a powershell script with this code to change some parameters in the Account policies :

```
secedit /export /cfg "$env:TEMP\security.cfg"
(Get-Content "$env:TEMP\security.cfg" -Raw) -replace 'PasswordComplexity = 1', 'PasswordComplexity = 0' | Set-Content "$env:TEMP\security.cfg"
# Set minimum password length (e.g., 0 characters)
$minPasswordLength = 0
(Get-Content "$env:TEMP\security.cfg" -Raw) -replace 'MinimumPasswordLength = \d+', "MinimumPasswordLength = $minPasswordLength" | Set-Content "$env:TEMP\security.cfg"
# Set maximum & minimum password age (e.g., 0 days)
$maxPasswordAge = 0
(Get-Content "$env:TEMP\security.cfg" -Raw) -replace 'MaximumPasswordAge = \d+', "MaximumPasswordAge = $maxPasswordAge" | Set-Content "$env:TEMP\security.cfg"
$minPasswordAge = 0
(Get-Content "$env:TEMP\security.cfg" -Raw) -replace 'MinimumPasswordAge = \d+', "MinimumPasswordAge = $minPasswordAge" | Set-Content "$env:TEMP\security.cfg"

secedit /configure /db "$env:windir\security\database\secedit.sdb" /cfg "$env:TEMP\security.cfg" /areas SECURITYPOLICY
```

But when I run it :
the only result I have is :

*The task has completed successfully.
See log %windir%\security\logs\scesrv.log for detail info.
Allows you to configure a system with security settings stored in a database.
The syntax of this command is:
secedit /configure /db filename [/cfg filename] [/overwrite][/areas area1 area2...] [/log filename] [/quiet]
/db filename - Specifies the database used to perform the security configuration.*

This is the syntax for the command.
And nothing has been changed in the security settings.

Is there an idea of what is wrong ?

Thanks for your help
BR
Jeronimo